# Why are polynomials of every degree significant in my linear regression?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, least-squares

My dataset consists of 1 million observations.

I am running a linear regression of Y on X (mean-centered and scaled variable), trying to demonstrate that there is a curvilinear relationship between the two variables of the form `lm(y ~ x + I(x^2)`.  This results in a significant coefficient on the squared term.  As a sanity check, I started adding polynomials of other degrees `I(x^3)`, `I(x^4)`, and so on, to see if these weren't significant.  To my chagrin, polynomials all the way up to I(x^30) were significant.

I assume this is partially because my dataset is so large, and thus detecting statistical significance is relatively easier due to high precision estimates.  So my question is:

> Why is this happening in my dataset? Is there a stricter way to test significance in big datasets? What is the correct way for detecting a curvilinear relationship in
>   big datasets between y and x?

Comment: What are you comparing significance against? You might find that the higher-degree model predicts better than a null model, but not significantly better than the low-degree model.

Comment: Prediction isn't really relevant for our task, but I assume I could use AIC/BIC to compare models?

Comment: That would work, or run an ANOVA between the models directly. What I'm trying to get at is maybe the coefficients on your higher-order terms are significantly different from 0 due  to the large amount of data, but do little to change the model output. If you see no significant difference in the outputs of the higher or lower order models (as measured by ANOVA), the extra terms aren't adding much.

Comment: +1 for running that sanity check.

Comment: You might try a GAM with a smoothing spline, which will penalize more terms and higher degree polynomials.

Comment: What *is* your task, if prediction isn't? If you are just assessing statistical significance for the sheer joy of it, then you already have your answer: there is a statistically significant curvilinear relationship in your data, and it's even more curvilinear than order 2. It will likely make little *practical* difference, but the other comments here have already been pointing that out. So: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @StephanKolassa: The task could be explanation, rather than prediction? In other words, understanding and describing the effect of X on Y? But even so, trying to plot Y vs X first via a high-density scatterplot (https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/151690_ac65a180e03641e2adc3cb2ecf6306c3.html) should be the first step in the modeling process. If the scatterplot indicates a smooth, non-linear effect of X on Y, then the bam() function from the mgcv package can be used to estimate it (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mgcv/versions/1.8-26/topics/bam).

Comment: @IsabellaGhement spot on.  Great suggestions.  Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, @Parseltongue. This thread should also come in handy: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22233/how-to-choose-significance-level-for-a-large-data-set.